# Idempotent JavaScript script loader

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

[I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74426379/9971404) an idempotent script loader (for the browser), where the same script won't be loaded more than once.

`scriptLoader.js`:

```js
let _loadingAndLoadedScripts = [];


export async function loadJs(src) {
  let hash = generateHash(src);

  // scenario 1: first invocation, so load script
  if (!_loadingAndLoadedScripts[hash]) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let tag  = document.createElement('script');
      tag.type = 'text/javascript';
      tag.id   = hash;
      tag.src  = src;

      tag.onload = () => {
        tag.setAttribute('data-loaded', true);
        document.dispatchEvent(new Event('scriptLoaded'));
        resolve();
      };

      tag.onerror = () => {
        console.error('Failed to load script \'' + src + '\'.');
        reject();
      }

      _loadingAndLoadedScripts[src] = true;    // save state
      document.body.appendChild(tag);
    });
  }

  // scenario 2: script is busy loading, or already loaded
  else {
    // if loaded, do nothing
    var script   = document.getElementById(hash);
    let isLoaded = script && script.getAttribute('data-loaded') === 'true';
    if (isLoaded) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
    // else loading, so wait
    else {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // ------------------ MAYBE WRAP IN TIMEOUT?
        document.addEventListener('scriptLoaded', (e) => {
          resolve();
        }, { 'once': true });
        // ------------------ MAYBE WRAP IN TIMEOUT?
      });
    }
  }

}


function generateHash(s) {
  // implementation irrelevant
}
```

**It works.**

But my JS is a bit rusty.I was thinking there could be a race condition whereby invocations 2+ (which wait for the script to load) would not register an event listener in time, and so wait forever for the event. A solution is to add a timer, and if it expires to `reject` the promise. I've shown that in the code above as `// MAYBE WRAP IN TIMEOUT?`.

This is the implementation I want to use inside of `//-----` ... `//-----`:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let timer;
  let eventName = 'scriptLoaded';
  let eventHandler = (event) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    resolve();
  }
  let eventOptions = { 'once': true };
  document.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, eventOptions);
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    document.removeEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, eventOptions);
    console.error('Failed to load script \'' + src + '\'.');
    reject();
  }, 10 * 1000);
});
```

**It works.**

But I'm wondering whether it's overkill and/or **unnecessary**? JS in the browser is single-threaded, so is it even possible that such a race condition would occur?

Answer (score 2):

A few issues

#### Needless use of async function

If you are not going to use the `await` keyword then a normal function would be sufficient.

#### Use `dataset` property instead of `setAttribute` with data attributes.

So instead of  `tag.setAttribute('data-loaded', true);` you can do `tag.dataset.dataLoaded = true;`. You may not even need to use this attribute at all.

#### Use Object or Map instead of Array for hash tables

Assuming your hash is a string like "2CF24...8B9824" then you should at least use an object for `_loadingAndLoadedScripts`. Let's use a `Map` object this time.

#### `data-loaded` attribute is unnecessary.

Since we will be using the returned promise to decide whether the script tag is loaded or not this is redundant.

OK now in your code the `loadJS` function returns a promise but you never use it. In fact that promise is exactly the only thing that you need. Accordingly we can trash that `scriptLoaded` event.

```
function generateHash(s) {
  // implementation irrelevant
}

export function loadJS(src, hash) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.type = 'text/javascript';
    tag.id = hash;
    tag.src = src;
    tag.onload = resolve;
    tag.onerror = e => {
      console.error('Failed to load script \'' + src + '\'.');
      tag.remove();
      reject({error:e,hash,src});
    }
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
  });
}

let _loadingAndLoadedScripts = new Map(),
    src  = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.15.0/ace.js",
    hash = generateHash(src);

if (!_loadingAndLoadedScripts.has(hash)) _loadingAndLoadedScripts.set(hash,loadJS(src,hash));
// if you want the promise way
_loadingAndLoadedScripts.get(hash)
                        .then(_ => { /* proceed with whatever code here */ })
                        .catch(e => ( _loadingAndLoadedScripts.delete(e.hash)
                                    , doSomethingWith(e.src,e.hash)
                                    ));

// or if you have top level await
try {
  await _loadingAndLoadedScripts.get(hash);
  // proceed with whatever code here 
} catch (e) {
   _loadingAndLoadedScripts.delete(e.hash);
   doSomeThingWith(e.src,e.hash);
}
```

We start with a source url as `src` and calculate it's `hash` with `generateHash` function then we pass them to the `loadJS` function which returns a promise which in return stored in the hash map `_loadingAndLoadedScripts` as `[hash, promise]` key value pairs.

So any time you have a source to create a new script tag to avoide a duplicate first check the hash table with the source string's hash. If it returns a promise then it's either already resolved (script loaded) or waiting. Whatever it's state just `await` or `.then()` it and proceed with the next source.

This workflow guarantees that the scripts are loaded in the order you invoke `loadJS`. You may add a timeout functionality to the `loadJS` file which rejects the promise once a certain time limit is reached. In this case you should remember that the hash table for that source has already been set so just  remove the etry with that hash from the hash table.

Answer (score 1):

### `scriptLoaded` event may be triggered by another script

```
1. Loading scriptA
2. Loading scriptB
3. Loading scriptB again
    3.1 waiting for scriptLoaded event
4. Loaded scriptA
    4.1 scriptLoaded event fired
    4.2 the second scriptB loading report finished incorrectly
```

### Cache the `Promise` instead could be another solution

```
if (script_url not in promiseCache) {
  promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    more stuff about loading script
  });
  promiseCache[script_url] = promise;
}
return promiseCache[script_url];
```

So you can avoid the event here.

Comment: Thanks tsh! Event may be triggered by other script: very nice catch, didn't think of that. I could fix it by raising it on a specific tag instead. Caching promise: which part of the code does that replace?